# Hyperbolic version of Sylvester co-linear problem

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, plane-geometry

Is the  hyperbolic version of  [Sylvester co linear problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem)   true?

Comment: Use the Klein model-- geodesics are straight lines.

Comment: Kelly's proof on your link works in absolute geometry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Use the projective (Cayley-Klein) model of the hyperbolic plane. Your points lie inside a disk. Hyperbolic lines are chords of that disk. Since the Euclidean Silvester-Gallai is true, you have the same conclusion in the hyperbolic case.

Comment: You should say "Cayley–Klein discovered by Beltrami"

Comment: Hi @AntonPetrunin Nothing against Beltrami, but then I will better say "projective model".